# How to get custom NuGet packages from a custom feed in Azure DevOps Artifacts into IntelliJ Rider

Tags: c#, intellij-idea, azure-devops, nuget

I have been trying to get custom NuGet packages from Azure DevOps Artifacts into IntelliJ Rider but could not make it work.

I am using:
Windows 10,
Rider 2022.3.2,
Developing solutions with .NET 6,
Feed: `https://[company-name].pkgs.visualstudio.com/[project-name]/_packaging/[feed-name]/nuget/v3/index.json`

Here is what **did not** work:

- Rider would not prompt me for credentials
- Entering credentials in the Rider NuGet window Sources tab did not help
- Manually editing the csproj to include a NuGet reference to a package on my custom feed did not help
- File | Invalidate Caches did not help
- Installing NuGet cli for Linux did not help
- Changing Rider's NuGet settings under Credential Providers to "NuGet/.NET CLI Plugins, then Rider integrated" did not help (or... it didn't help by itself)
- Restarting Rider after doing any of these various things did not help

The NuGet window Log tab just kept saying that I had cancelled the request to get the packages from my feed.

How do I import a NuGet artifact into IntelliJ Rider?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the situation by following these steps:

1. Download and install [Azure Artifacts Credentials Provider](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider#azure-artifacts-credential-provider) script and run it
2. Manually add your artifact reference to csproj. For example `<PackageReference Include="[my-package]" Version="1.0.0-preview.1" />`
3. Turn on command line, navigate your `.sln` folder and run `dotnet restore --interactive`
4. Follow login instructions and log into the subscription you want to pull artifacts from
5. Restart IntelliJ Rider

This answer is inspired from Smphayward's answer in [rider support page](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009631420-Using-NuGet-feed-of-private-azure-devops-projects-with-oauth2-not-working)